# Работа с Memo и Image

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Доброго времени суток, дорогие хэшкодеры. У меня будет несколько вопросов касательно работы с Memo и Image.

1. Меня интересуют стили текста. Как сделать так, чтобы они менялись и в Image, и можно ли в Memo изменить лишь часть стиля текста?
2. Как сделать отлавливание русского текста?
3. Как при вставке картинки в Image сделать так, чтобы при написании текст обтекал рисунок, а не писался по нему?

Заранее спасибо. В случае, если мои вопросы звучат некорректно, то с радостью попытаюсь как-то иначе их сформулировать.

Comment: То, что с RichEdit это намного легче, я понимаю, но хочется попробовать именно так.

Comment: Просто для развлечения? ) 
Тогда первый вариант, расширяйте функционал Memo, изобретайте колесо

Comment: Меня не интересует определение раскладки, ну, если я правильно поняла, можно попробовать через процедуру это сделать, прописать все строчные и прописные.
Ладно, отложу изобретение колеса, и вернусь к идее с RichEdit)) Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или писать наследника и дописывать функционал, или использовать сторонний компонент, или посмотреть в сторону RichEdit, ибо Memo не работает с форматированием.

- "Меня интересуют стили текста. Как сделать так, чтобы они менялись и в Image"

  При выводе текста в Image? Image.Canvas.Font.Style
- "и можно ли в Memo изменить лишь часть стиля текста?"

  Стандартными методами не предусмотрен Memo для форматирования, стилизации и вставки рисунков.
- "Как сделать отлавливание русского текста?"

Что значит отлавливание? Отличить в Memo русский от латинского или спросить у системы текущую раскладку клавиатуры?

- "Как при вставке картинки в Image сделать так, чтобы при написании текст обтекал рисунок, а не писался по нему?"

  Это всё ещё относится к "Image в Memo"? Или просто при рисовании на Image? Если второе, то при выводе текста позиционирование смещаем на ширину картинки плюс отступ, если первое, то вы всё равно сделаете подобие RichEdit в итоге, т.к. нужно будет добавлять в текст маркеры форматирования, распознавать их при выводе и прочее.